# Cascading dropdown selected value

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 dropdowns. 1. Select country 2. Select school 3. select course.

I have the following code for this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#CountriesID").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Account/SchoolList/" + $("#CountriesID").val(), function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Select your school</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, school) {
                items += "<option value='" + school.Value + "'>" + school.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Schools").html(items);
        });
    });

    $("#Schools").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Account/CourseList/" + $("#Schools").val(), function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Select your Course</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, course) {
                items += "<option value='" + course.Value + "'>" + course.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Courses").html(items);
        });
    });
});
```

This is working good.
Now, If someone saves this information and come back to his profile page again, I need to show the saved value as selected option.

I have the saved schoolid and courseid in Viewbag.
But how do I use that viewbag values as the SELECTED in the above code ??

Comment: setting the selected value in `#Schools` would trigger the async call then you could on success set the selected value of `#Course`, you could do this by moving the `$.getJSON` code to a function that allows for a callback or use the `$.when` function.  If you need a demo i'll be happy to supply one as an answer.  This should be enough to get you off to the races.

Comment: ya plz show me a demo..that would be great actually

Comment: You'll need to save the country id too in the ViewBag to make my solution complete, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: yes, I did that...there is something wrong when showing the school value from viewbag. I wrote it in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/huNx9/4/)

This is only one way of doing this, there are many many more.  I also would recommend sending the country code since you'll need that to fill all three drop downs.

**JS**

```
function GetSchools(country) {
    return $.getJSON("/Account/SchoolList/" + country, function (data) {
        var items = "<option>Select your school</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, school) {
            items += "<option value='" + school.Value + "'>" + school.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#Schools").html(items);
    });
}

function GetCourses(school) {
    return $.getJSON("/Account/CourseList/" + , function (data) {
        var items = "<option>Select your Course</option>";
        $.each(data, function (i, course) {
            items += "<option value='" + course.Value + "'>" + course.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#Courses").html(items);
    });
}

function OnSuccess(){
    if('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.courseid)' != '')
    {
        $('#Schools').val(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.courseid));
    }
}

$(function () {
    $("#CountriesID").change(function () {
        //Clears the list of Courses since the Country Changed
        $("#Courses").empty();

        //Gets the list of Schools for the new Country
        GetSchools(this.val());
    });

    $("#Schools").change(function () {
        //Gets the list of Courses for the selected school
        GetCourses(this.val());
    });

    if('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.schoolid)' != '')
    {
        $('#Schools').val(@Html.Raw(ViewBag.schoolid));
        $.when(GetCourses('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.schoolid)')).then(OnSuccess);
    }

});
```

Updated 9/17/2013 4:29PM

Comment: hi..I have added if('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.CountryId)'!='')
        {
            $("#CountriesID").val('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.CountryId)');
        } to get the country..the country and course works just fine. But the school value doesn't show up on the dropdown list. If I see it on firebug, I can see this: if ('9' != '')
{
$('#Schools').val('9');
$.when(GetCourses('9')).then(OnSuccess);
} ..But still the dropdown shows nothing...what could be wrong??

Answer (score 0):

If you are having your code in `View`, you may write something like following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var schoolID = "@ViewBag.schoolID";
    var courceID = "@ViewBag.courceID";

    $("#Schools option:selected").val(schoolID);
    $("#Course option:selected").val(courceID);
});
```

If you are having this code in separate js file, you may use hiden divs to get ViewBags data.

Comment: it doesn't work..even if it works, will it not just display that ViewBag value on the dropdown and not the whole list? I need to show the whole list but the ViewBag value will be selected meaning if users click on the dropdown, they will see other values as well..